# Three js - Set camera to Loaded object

Tags: javascript, three.js

Just wondering how i would go about centering the camera around the model loaded through the stl loader.

I've been playing with variables for ages, I've tried setting the mesh position manually to (0,0,0), and also the camera to (0,0,0) even then, the camera is not centered on the design!

Here's the relevant code:

```
function init() {

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
            camera.position.set( 0,60 , 100 );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
            controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0xcccccc, 0.002 );


            var callbackProgress = function( progress, result ) {

                var bar = 250,
                    total = progress.totalModels + progress.totalTextures,
                    loaded = progress.loadedModels + progress.loadedTextures;

                if ( total )
                    bar = Math.floor( bar * loaded / total );

                $( \"bar\" ).style.width = bar + \"px\";

                count = 0;
                for ( var m in result.materials ) count++;

                handle_update( result, Math.floor( count/total ) );

            }
            var callbackFinished = function ( result ) {

                loaded = result;

                document.getElementById(\"message\").style.display = \"none\";

                handle_update( result, 1 );

            }

             document.getElementById(\"progress\").style.display = \"block\";
            // world
            var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

                var geometry = event.content;
                var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0xff5533, color: 0xff5533, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
                var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

                mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                mesh.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0 );
                mesh.scale.set( 2,2,2 );

                mesh.castShadow = true;
                mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                camera.position.set( geometry.x,geometry.y , 100 );
                scene.add( mesh );

            } );
            loader.callbackProgress = callbackProgress;
            loader.load('somefile.stl',callbackFinished); 

            // lights

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( 1, 1, 1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
            light.position.set( -1, -1, -1 );
            scene.add( light );

            light = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
            scene.add( light );


            // renderer

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: false } );
            renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container = document.getElementById( 'container' );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
            /*
            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );*/

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }
```

Comment: Do you actually want the camera to be at the same location as the model, like first person view, or are you trying to look at the model? I notice that you are not telling the camera what to look at or where to point.

Comment: What i want is a view of the model, with the model at the center of the view. I'm very new to this three.js stuff, but it is truly amazing tech ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have confused the position of the camera with it's target.

To get the camera to focus on the model, try `camera.lookAt(mesh.position);`, and make sure that the camera isn't inside of the model, e.g. `camera.position.set(0, 60, 100);`, your original camera position, or `geometry.x, geometry.y, 100`, to look at the model from the side , directly down the Z axis.

Comment: I don't have a model variable, how would i go about declaring that? Or is it declared when the model is loaded?

Comment: Oops, my bad, I meant `mesh`, not `model`.